# Apache Spark to add numbers from an ArrayList

Tags: arraylist, apache-spark

I was looking for a Spark program that adds the elements of an existing Integer ArrayList.I went through all transformations and actions in apache spark but couldn't find a suitable one to just add the elements.

If someone could tell me how to write the code for the above ie add elements of an arraylist in spark , then it'll be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a RDD[Int] as shown below:

```
val myRdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

you could do the following to add the elements of the List:

```
myRdd.reduce(_+_)

res1: Int = 21
```

Or you could do the following as well:

```
myRdd.fold(0)(_+_)

res6: Int = 21
```

Hope it helps.